# CSS ONLY - Remove overlay (or Make overlay disappear) when mouse not over sidebar

Tags: html, css, overlay, sidebar

I am wondering how to make the overlay disappear as soon as the mouse is not on the sidebar menu when the screen size is below 1024px

This is the html of the nav

```
<!--BEGINNING NAV-->

<ul id="nav">
    <div id="navImg">
        <img src="img/YouTube-logo.png" id="youtubeLogo" alt='Website Logo'>
        <!--BEGINNING OVERLAY-->
        <div id="overlayBack"></div>
        <div id="myOverlay" class="overlay">
            <!-- Overlay content -->
            <div class="overlay-content">
                <a href="#">Services</a>
                <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--END OVERLAY-->
    </div>
    <div id="menuItem">
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
<!--End NAV-->
```

This is the CSS.

```
/*End Scale Effect*/

[class*="col-"] {
    width: 33.33%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    [class*="col-"] {
        width: 50%;
    }
    #menuItem li {
        display: none;
    }
    #navImg:hover .overlay {
        width: 30%;
    }
    #navImg:hover #overlayBack {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    #overlayBack:hover {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    [class*="col-"] {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #menuItem li {
        display: none;
    }
    #navImg:hover .overlay {
        width: 100%;
    }
}


/*End Responsive*/

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 45px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(244, 67, 54, 1.0);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin-top: 25px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.overlay a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#overlayBack {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    z-index: -3;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

If you see the snippet you will notice that on hover of the logo the sidebar shows up and there is an overlay behind the sidebar. However, when I leave the sidebar I would like also to have the sidebar go away and make the overlay disappear as well.

Any idea how to accomplish this.

Thank you ver much.

```css
/*End Scale Effect*/

[class*="col-"] {
    width: 33.33%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    [class*="col-"] {
        width: 50%;
    }
    #menuItem li {
        display: none;
    }
    #navImg:hover .overlay {
        width: 30%;
    }
    #navImg:hover #overlayBack {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    #overlayBack:hover {
        display: none;
    }
}


/*End Responsive*/

.row p {
    -webkit-word-break: keep-all;
    -moz-word-break: keep-all;
    -ms-word-break: keep-all;
    -o-word-break: keep-all;
    word-break: keep-all;
}

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 45px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(244, 67, 54, 1.0);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin-top: 25px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.overlay a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#overlayBack {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    z-index: -3;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
        <div id="navImg">
            <img src="img/YouTube-logo.png" id="youtubeLogo" alt='Website Logo'>
            <!--BEGINNING OVERLAY-->
            <div id="overlayBack"></div>
            <div id="myOverlay" class="overlay">
                <!-- Overlay content -->
                <div class="overlay-content">
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--END OVERLAY-->
        </div>
        <div id="menuItem">
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        </div>
    </ul>
```

Comment: From what I see, the black overlay disappears when I leave the sidebar... if im wrong, then i need more clarification.

Comment: Hello @InvincibleM, if you leave the sidebar going towards the top in the logo area, everything seems to disappear. But if you leave the sidebar going towards "the content area" and end up on the black overlay, the sidebar does not go away and the overlay does not go away.

Comment: Ok, @Kirshna, if i understood correctly, you want to not keep the navigation menu open while you hover on the black overlay?

Comment: @invincibleM, that is correct. The black overlay is just to mask the content while the sidebar navigation is open. The sidebar navigation is activated by the over on the logo image. but it looks like the only way to remove it right now is to go back around the area of the logo image.
But wondering if there is a way to have the sidebar disappear as well the overlay as soon as the mouse is not longer over the sidebar in any way.

Answer (score 1):

OH MY GOSH IM STUPID AS HECK. Ok so i noticed that for some reason the CSS was not hiding the `#overlayBack` css id. I just styled in html like so:

```
<div id="overlayBack"></div>
```

to

```
<div id="overlayBack" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Here is a running example:

```css
/*End Scale Effect*/

[class*="col-"] {
    width: 33.33%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    [class*="col-"] {
        width: 50%;
    }
    #menuItem li {
        display: none;
    }
    #navImg:hover .overlay {
        width: 30%;
    }
    #navImg:hover #overlayBack {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    #overlayBack:hover {
        display: none;
    }
}


/*End Responsive*/

.row p {
    -webkit-word-break: keep-all;
    -moz-word-break: keep-all;
    -ms-word-break: keep-all;
    -o-word-break: keep-all;
    word-break: keep-all;
}

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 45px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(244, 67, 54, 1.0);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin-top: 25px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.overlay a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#overlayBack {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    z-index: -3;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
        <div id="navImg">
            <img src="img/YouTube-logo.png" id="youtubeLogo" alt='Website Logo'>
            <!--BEGINNING OVERLAY-->
            <div id="overlayBack" style="display:none;"></div>
            <div id="myOverlay" class="overlay">
                <!-- Overlay content -->
                <div class="overlay-content">
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--END OVERLAY-->
        </div>
        <div id="menuItem">
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        </div>
    </ul>
```

Hopefully, this helps, and if it that's great and good luck with your site!

Comment: @InvicibleM, That is interesting. Thank you for this solution. I actually need the overlay there to mask the content. but it is interesting that when you have the display to none for the overlayBack the sidenav behaves like it should. So i believe the way i have the black overlay could be the issue. Is there another way to have the overlay show up when the sidenav is shown?

Comment: Yea, but i think it requires JS and im not sure how to implement it. But maybe tomorrow i can figure something out.

Comment: Thanks @InvincibleM. it is appreciated. Meanwhile, i will look at it again to see if i can crack it. :)